# Crystal Report not supporting to style attribute of Paragraph tag

Tags: html, css, crystal-reports

Crystal Report is not supporting the style attribute of the paragraph tag. Why this is happening? Just freaked out with this problem since yesterday.
Here is my HTML code which is I am putting on the Crystal Report:

```
paragraph tag"<p>".Style attribute inside it like - "
style="text-align:justify" Text is to test Text is to test 
Text is to test Text is to testText is to testText is to test
close paragraph tag"</p>"
```

But this is not adjusting in report. Text is going to left side only.

Is there any solution?? Please help.
I will be so much thankful for that..
regards
- Devdan

Comment: please refer the link http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp

Comment: can you show the required output how are you looking for a paragraph

Comment: Instead of going for `HTML` tags you can just use the `Justified` in `Horizontal Allignement` option in `Fomat field` of the object

Comment: Siva, can you make your comment answer?